# create permitted attributes for my form post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following output from my form post and I want to create permitted attributes but I am not able to get it to work and a little confused.

POST data:-

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"nUAxX0FRhqhS+u8zTUcvogtHf8KPhcriNK95zLL0mAwd+/CyUrq80+wdq68c/h2MrBWvvTdBYwHv3IKH29ZcWQ==",
>   "quiz"=>{"name"=>"Questions Testing",
>   "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"question_name"=>"Question # 1",
>   "answer1"=>"", "answer2"=>"", "answer3"=>"", "answer4"=>"",
>   "correct_answer"=>""}, "1"=>{"question_name"=>"", "answer1"=>"",
>   "answer2"=>"", "answer3"=>"", "answer4"=>"", "correct_answer"=>""}}},
>   "commit"=>"Create Quiz"}

**error**:-
Unpermitted parameter: questions_attributes

What I have tried is

> params.require(:quiz).permit(:name, questions_attributes: [{0:
>   [:question_name, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4]}])

And I am not able to understand , how to get this to work so any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your association is something like

Quiz `has_many` Questions

and you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` in your `quiz.rb`

If the above is correct, Use

`params.require(:quiz).permit(:name, questions_attributes: [:question_name, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4])`

This should work as rails will handle it. Also refer [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes) article for understanding the way rails works for nested attributes. It explains the same in a very simple manner.

If the error persists, please post it and i'll try to help better.

Comment: No it works perfectly .. thanks for the help .. really appreciate it